# Can Fisher Information Matrix be calculated numerically through finite differentiation?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, fisher-information, numerical-integration, fisher-scoring

In GLMs (generalized linear models), the negative of the [Fisher information matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Matrix_form) takes the form of a cross product between covariates $\mathbf{X}$ and a diagonal matrix:
$$
\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{X}
$$

Assuming that one is using maximum likelihood on a probability density function $p(z|y)$, applying an inverse link function $z = g(\mathbf{x}^T \beta)$ as parameter to that probability distribution (where $\beta$ are the model coefficients), the **Hessian** (**observed** information matrix) also takes a similar product form $\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{W} \mathbf{X}$, with a diagonal matrix $W$ in which each entry is the second derivative observation-wise of the log-likelihood for each point:

$$
W_{i,i} = \frac{\partial^2 f(x_i|y_i) }{\partial x_i^2}
$$
$$
f(x|y) = -\log( p( g(x) | y) )
$$
$$
x_i = \mathbf{x}^T_i \beta
$$

In the case of the Hessian, the entries in this diagonal matrix can in theory be approximated numerically through finite differencing based only on evaluation calls to $\log(p(z|y))$ and $g(x)$; or potentially based on finite differencing on the gradient $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$:
$$
g(x_i) \approx \frac{ f(x_i + \triangle|y_i) - f(x_i|y_i) }{\triangle}
$$
$$
W_{i,i} \approx \frac{ g(x_i + \triangle) - g(x_i) }{\triangle}
$$

Now my question: is there some equivalent numerical approximation for the diagonal entries in the **Fisher** information matrix, that could be calculated based only on evaluations of $p(z)$, $\log(p(z|y))$, and $g(x)$ plus their derivatives; but **without knowing anything about variances** of the probability distributions, and without assuming anything additional about the link function? (e.g. that would work for non-cannonical link functions)

Or perhaps some procedure involving monte carlo sampling to approximate integrals based on evaluations on these functions in place of variances and expectations of integrals?

Comment: I believe most, if not all, software to fit a GLM already computes the Fisher information matrix numerically.

Comment: @whuber Yes, they compute them based on gradients and variances. But my question is whether the numbers could in theory be obtained for an arbitrary likelihood and link without knowing the variances or without solving any infinite integral.

Comment: I don't follow your distinction about "knowing the variances" or "infinite integral."  Perhaps you could provide an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: I share whuber's confusion about the specifics of your question, but yes in general, one can evaluate the expectation via Monte Carlo $\mathbb{E}_y[\nabla \log f(y|\theta) \nabla \log f(y|\theta)^\top] \approx \frac{1}{K} \sum_{y_k\sim f(y|
\theta)}\nabla \log f(y_k|\theta) \nabla \log f(y_k|\theta)^\top$  and, if you really must, you can calculate the gradient $\nabla \log f(y_k|\theta)$ via finite differencing (but why on earth would you do that when we have automatic differentiation ;)).

Comment: @whuber What I mean is: typically this would be calculated as $\frac{ (\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x} )^2}{\text{Var}_{p}(g(x))}$ - i.e. it requires knowing the variance of the probability distribution from which the log-likelihood is calculated. As for why I'm looking for an approximation: I'd like to have some way of verifying by numerical simulations that the derivation of a Fisher matrix for a given likelihood is correct.

Comment: @anymous.asker: Are you thinking outside of a generalized linear model framework (within which the conditional variance of each observation is easily derived)? That is by "arbitrary likelihood" you mean not an exponential dispersion family?

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Yes, I was wondering about arbitrary cases - e.g. composite models like Tobit's or Heckman's for example, or distributions that are not in the exponential family like Dirichlet parameterized by concentrations (variance is still easy to derive there though).

Comment: The relation between Fisher information, conditional variance & squared score is particular to GLMs too. As are the terms *canonical* & *non-canonical* link: GLMs seem to be rather a red herring here. On the other hand, for maximum-likelihood estimation in general what is there to to say beyond what @JohnMadden said above?

Comment: @JohnMadden Thanks, that's a very straightforward idea that gives the correct answer. But how would that expectation work in the case of e.g. an ordered logit model? In such case, if $y$ were to be drawn according to the predicted probabilities and gradients calculated on it, I think that expectation would not match with what [VGAM calculates](https://github.com/cran/VGAM/blob/7b4211c0d4b828fcdd6644ed86c6dac92e80148c/R/family.categorical.R#L1893) for example.

Comment: @anymous.asker oh interesting, regretfully I don't know much about VGAM or specific strategies for optimization of ordered logit models, but it sounds like they are using a different preconditioner than the true Fisher info, in which case indeed this scheme would not match it.